# Jquery MixItUp list to grid view change

Tags: jquery, html, css, mixitup

Whenever I find an example of using MixItUp to show list or grid view, everytime I see that grid view is made of 4 columns. Can I make grid list with different number of columns? And if can, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research i found out, that MixItUp`s grid is based on your CSS setup.

Have a look at this:
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/responsive-grids/

Scroll down a little to the "inline-block" section and take a look at the second example. This shows a 3 column grid.